# Updating to Snow Leopard through a USB optical drive

Tags: snow-leopard, usb, optical-drive

My optical drive on my Macbook Pro has gone out. I have a copy of Snow Leopard on a disc, if I borrow a USB optical drive, will I be able to install Snow Leopard and is this a reliable method? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should work perfectly well. Almost all USB optical drives use [standard drivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usb_mass_storage), so just about any one should work just fine with your MacBook Pro.